# How to save user survey responses to open-ended questions?

Tags: mysql, database, rest

I am designing a MySQL database for storing profiles and user responses to questions from these profiles. Data from the database is needed to create a json objects. We are developing a REST API.

The user fills in the data (`name`,`email`, `position`,`tel` ...) and thus receives `user.id`. Then answers survey questions. As a result, user responses are stored in the `answer` table.

User's response can be prepared in advance in the `options` table (closed-ended questions). Or maybe not prepared (open-ended questions). Therefore, in addition to the table `answer_options`, which contains the user's choice of answers (many-to-many), the table`answer` contains the following fields:

- `text` (answer to the question as text),
- `num` (answer to the question as a number),
- `yn` (answer to the question as a boolean type).

The table `input_types` contains the type of the html element (for example,`<input type = "text" />`.
The table `insert_types` contains the name of the field in the table `answer` (`yn`,`text`, `num` or`options`).
API returns questions as an JSON object:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "label": "Annual turnover of the company?",
  "placeholder": "Enter a number",
  "required": true,
  "input_type": {
    "name": "text"
  },
  "insert_type": {
    "name": "num"
  }
}
```

Front-end looks at `insert_type` send an JSON object relying on it to answer the question:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "question": 1,
    "num": 100
}
```

API recives an object and saves it in the `answer` table (the`num` property is saved in `answer.num`)

I don't like the fact that the front-end has to concern about `insert_type`. How is it customary to save user survey responses to open-ended questions?
[image: MYSQL DB model]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project before. What I did was add user's open ended answers to options table as well, and use the answer_options table for all the answer.

For the front end, it can always send the answer value without specifying the insert type. The backend can find the option_id for close ended questions, or insert the answer for open ended questions and get the option_id. Just for your reference.